# CI doesn't upload file despite correct config options

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

I'm creating a page which will require the user to submit a file, it also saves the filename in the db along with some other data.

I've tried using the `$_FILES` superglobal to manually configure the file attributes allowed which for some reason didn't upload, I then decided to use CI's file upload class which is way more simple. I'm stuck with the same problem but with easier code to work with:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   $data = $this->input->post('input');
   $this->security->xss_clean($data);

        $config['upload_path'] = './photos/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']     = '1000000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {

          $error = array('error'  =>  $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
        else {
      //Form validation and insert of filename as a string
  }
}
```

I expect it to return true and insert a new record into the DB as well as save the file, none of these however, happen. By the way I use `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to save the file name in the DB, I assume that there's another way of doing this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look to [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data) of the `data()` method of `upload` to get info on the uploaded file - including the name, e.g.

```
$fileName = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

But that's not helpful if the upload is failing. Is that still the case with the CI code? If so, what does `$error` contain?

Comment: `print_r($error);` says `Array ( [error] =>

The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.
) `

Comment: Yup, that will prevent the upload. Most likely due to file permissions. Set the permissions to 777 - which is read/write for anybody.

Comment: is permission within the `$config` array?

Comment: No. You will have to use your computer's file browser to find the directory and set the permissions. Depending on your OS that might be found under "properties" for the folder.

Comment: I use Ubuntu - Linux

Comment: Then you can do it using whatever "file manager" your desktop has handy. Or you can use a terminal window command line. The "how-to" for that should be easy enough to find online.

Comment: yea that part is ez